# Using variable inside a for in loop, doesn't considered to be read by compiler...why is that?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, llvm, analyzer

I have an `NSArray`, and I am declaring that variable inside a function locally and used inside in for loop. But while I `Analyze` code it appears to be an error or an issue. The issue is `Dead store - Values stored to 'elements' during initialisation is never read.` But I do use that variable inside a for in loop...

Visual Description :

[image]

So the question is, Why compiler says that after creating `NSArray` I haven't read anywhere in my code?

P.S. Code runs as I intended, but I just want to know why is this issue showing up?

Thanks for any explanation given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allocating memory for `elemnts` and initialising it, and then two lines later you overwrite that variable having never used the allocated memory!

Just write this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *elements = [[alarmLevelsDoc rootElement] elementsForName:@"AlarmLevel"];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is allocating space for the array, but not using that space.
When you assign:

```
 elements = [[alarmLevelsDoc rootElement] elementsForName:@"AlarmLevel"];
```

you are pointing that variable at another memory space, so the first one is useless.

You can fix this by just deleting your first line, and making your elements line like this:

```
 NSArray *elements = [[alarmLevelsDoc rootElement] elementsForName:@"AlarmLevel"];
```